# MariaDB ColumnStore: Filtering SubQuery by Computed Value

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery, mariadb, columnstore

I have a table which, for a given `(time, country, asn)` tuple, stores several metrics:

```
+----------+---------+-------+-------+--------+--------+
|   time   | country |  asn  |  rtt  |  rexb  |  reqs  |
+----------+---------+-------+-------+--------+--------+
| 10000000 |   US    | 12345 |  40   |  0.05  |  5000  |
| 10000000 |   US    | 54321 |  120  |  0.15  |  500   |
| 10000000 |   MX    | 12345 |  300  |  0.25  |  1000  |
| 10000000 |   MX    | 54321 |  160  |  0.10  |  200   |
|   ....   |   ...   |  ...  |  ...  |  ....  |  ....  |
```

During general use I normalize each of these metrics to a value between 0 and 100, then return the greatest value in order to get a rough estimate for "how good" the connection is to that ASN in that country:

```
SELECT
    country,
    asn,
    least(
        -- least(100, greatest(0, ...)) = clip value between 0 and 100
        least(100, greatest(0,
            -- normalize and protect against null values
            -- sample normalization:
            --     0 ms RTT = "100% good"
            --     300 ms RTT = "0% good"
            coalesce((300 - rtt) / 3, 0)
        )),
        least(100, greatest(0,
            -- sample normalization:
            --     0% REXB = "100% good"
            --     50% REXB = "0% good"
            coalesce((0.5 - rexb) / 0.5, 0)
        )),
        -- Other metrics may follow
    ) as quality
FROM
    metrics
WHERE
    time = 10000000 -- "current time"
```

Occasionally I may perform weighted averages by using the `reqs` (number of requests to that country+ASN) column for weighting:

```
SELECT
    country,
    least(
        least(100, greatest(0,
            coalesce((300 - sum(rtt*reqs)/sum(reqs)) / 3, 0)
        )),
        least(100, greatest(0,
            coalesce((0.5 - sum(rexb*reqs)/sum(reqs)) / 0.5, 0)
        ))
    ) as avg_quality
FROM
    metrics
WHERE
    time = 10000000 -- "current time"
GROUP BY
    country
```

This query works perfectly. I just ran into an issue, however, when I tried to use this in a subquery.

My goal was to find how many countries had an "average quality" below a certain threshold:

```
SELECT 
    count(*)
FROM (
    SELECT
        country,
        least(
            least(100, greatest(0,
                coalesce((300 - sum(rtt*reqs)/sum(reqs)) / 3, 0)
            )),
            least(100, greatest(0,
                coalesce((0.5 - sum(rexb*reqs)/sum(reqs)) / 0.5, 0)
            ))
        ) as avg_quality
    FROM
        metrics
    WHERE
        time = 10000000 -- "current time"
    GROUP BY
        time, country
) t1
WHERE t1.avg_quality < 50
```

This threw the error:

```
ERROR 1815 (HY000): Internal error: Lost connection to ExeMgr. Please contact your administrator
```

I can perform simpler subqueries without an issue. Why does this one fail, and how do I fix it?

I'm using MariaDB and the `metrics` table uses the ColumnStore engine.

### Quick Update

When I replace `WHERE t1.avg_quality < 50` with `WHERE country = "US"` the query executes without an issue. So it has no trouble performing the subquery or filtering. It's strictly when I try to filter on a computed column that it fails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reached out to the DBAs at my company to see if they had any answers or suggestions. They were not able to provide an explanation for the behavior, but they were able to provide a work-around:

```
SELECT 
    count(*)
FROM (
    SELECT
        country,
        least(
            least(100, greatest(0,
                coalesce((300 - sum(rtt*reqs)/sum(reqs)) / 3, 0)
            )),
            least(100, greatest(0,
                coalesce((0.5 - sum(rexb*reqs)/sum(reqs)) / 0.5, 0)
            ))
        ) as avg_quality
    FROM
        metrics
    WHERE
        time = 10000000 -- "current time"
    GROUP BY
        time, country
    HAVING
        avg_quality < 50
) t1
```